# How to get data from clicking with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So, I'm trying to get more data from a page dependening on what I selected on a dropdown List using Scrapy.

Visit: http://grace.itam.mx/EDSUP/BWZKSENP.P_Horarios1?s=1416

In the Code below, first I get all the elements of the dropdown List, and it is working fine.

But I would like also to get the info after selecting an Element and then clicking submbit to go to a new page with a data table. Is there anyway to do that ?

```
# run this file as
# scrapy runspider scrappy-itam.py -t csv -o s4-out.csv
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from collections import OrderedDict
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 's4'
    allowed_domains = ['grace.itam.mx']
    start_urls = [ "http://grace.itam.mx/EDSUP/BWZKSENP.P_Horarios1?s=1416"]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        for cour in response.xpath("//div[@class='pagebodydiv']/form/select/option/text()"):
             item = OrderedDict()
             info=cour.extract()
             course=info.split('-')
             item['Department']=course[0]
             item['Course']=course[2]
             items.append(item)
        return items
```

**Edit:**
Here I used the FormRequest to parse the new page.

```
lass MySpider(Spider):
name = 's4'
allowed_domains = ['grace.itam.mx']
start_urls = [ "http://grace.itam.mx/EDSUP/BWZKSENP.P_Horarios1?s=1416"]

def parse(self, response):
    for c in response.xpath("//div[@class='pagebodydiv']/form/select/option/text()"):
         item = OrderedDict()
         info=c.extract()
         yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'TXT_MATERIA':info},callback=self.after_button)


def after_button(self,response):
    yield response.xpath("//div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/b/text()").extract()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Scrapy [FormRequest.from_response](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects) using as parameter the values from the Element you want to select. This way, you can parse the other page's content on another method in your spider.

**EDIT 1:**

In your `FormRequest` there is a mistake. Change it to:

```
scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'txt_materia':info, 's' : '1416'})
```

I don't think adding the `s : 1416` parameter is a requirement, but `txt_materia` should be lowercase. When I used it as the code above the responses were corrrect.

In your `after_button` method, I've found two minor mistakes:

1. Don't xpath on `tbody`. Use relative paths to avoid them!
2. As the error message stated, you can't simply yield from Spider the result from that xpath. You must return a Request, BaseItem, dict or None.

This is the code I wrote for `after_button`:

```
def after_button(self,response):
    yield { "text" : response.xpath("//div[3]/table[1]//tr[1]/td[1]/b/text()").extract_first() }
```

Comment: Thank you Lucas, I Will try it

Comment: I would have added code for it, but you'll see it's pretty straight forward. FormRequest looks for a form in the page, fills it with the parameters you specify in the request and send it.

If you find yourself in trouble using it, I'll edit my answer with code later on.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I tried to use it, but every time I call the ForrmRequest , the Spider goes to the same page every time. And I got this error message: 
'Spider must return Request, BaseItem,
 dict or None, got 'str' in <POST http://grace.itam.mx/EDSUP/BWZKSENP.P_Horarios2>'.
 I edited the question so you can see what I've done.

Comment: @LuisEduardoDelfinAresDePa I edited my answer with new info and a few corrections to your `FormRequest`

Comment: I also want to add that, I didn't know exactly what element you wanted to scrape with the xpath present in `after_button`, so I'm pretty sure the xpath I posted won't fetch exactly the data you want. I am focusing on helping you with the FormRequest because it is the questions aim.

Comment: Now I understand how it works. Thank you very much Lucas.